# The list is not getting refreshed

Tags: angular, angular-material-table

The list is not getting refreshed after adding or deleting an item. I have to refresh my page to see the change. The response is also not getting refreshed in the network tab.

Calling the POST endpoint to add the item.

```
 addpaymentMethod() {
    this.billingService.savePaymentMethod(this.paymentMethodData).subscribe((response: any) => {
      if (response) {
        console.log(response);
        this.dialogRef.close(response.result);
      }
    },
      (error: any) => {
        this.dialogRef.close('error');
      })
  }
```

Calling the get endpoint after closing the popup:

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    this.isPaymentMethod = true;
    if (res === true) {
      this.loadPaymentMethods(); //calling the get endpoint.
      this.openMsgDialog('Payment method added successfully!', 'success');
    }
  });
```

// Defining the get endpoint to view the list item.

```
 loadPaymentMethods() {
    var reqParams;
    if (this.isUnitDetails) {
      var unitId = this.isResetData ? this.selectedItem.unitId : this.currentItem.unitId;
      reqParams = "locationId=" + this.currentItem.locationId + "&unitId=" + unitId + "&customerTransactionId=" + this.currentItem.customerTransactionId;
    }
    else {
      reqParams = "locationId=" + this.selectedVacantUnitDetails.locationId + "&unitId=" + this.selectedVacantUnitDetails.unitId + "&customerTransactionId=" + this.selectedVacantUnitDetails.transactionId;
    }
    this.tenantFormsBillingService.getPaymentMethods(reqParams).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.datasource.data = res.data; //showing the data in the table.
    })
  }
```

Comment: Can you give an example code on stackblitz?

Comment: @Beller, I am working with the third party payment integration and cannot upload the code there due to the privacy.